# ReferenceError: error is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

ReferenceError: error is not defined in the code:

```
app.post('/register', function(req, res) {
  var hash = bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(10));
  var user = new User({
    firstName: req.body.firstName,
    lastName: req.body.lastName,
    email: req.body.email,
    password: hash,
  });
  user.save(function(err) {
    if (err) {
      var err = 'Something bad happened, try again!';
      if(err.code === 11000) {
        error = 'That email is already taken, try another.';
      }
      res.render('register.jade', { error: error });
    } else {
      res.redirect('/dashboard');
    }
  });
});
```

Specifically the error is on this line I believe:

```
  res.render('register.jade', { error: error });
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix this. I thought I defined it when I put in:

```
  if(err.code === 11000) {
        error = 'That email is already taken, try another.';
   }
```

The error I received is:

```
/Users/darceymckelvey/Documents/auth/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:779
      catch(err) { process.nextTick(function() { throw err}); }
                                                       ^
ReferenceError: error is not defined
    at /Users/darceymckelvey/Documents/auth/app.js:57:44
    at /Users/darceymckelvey/Documents/auth/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:1747:19
    at handleError (/Users/darceymckelvey/Documents/auth/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/hooks-fixed/hooks.js:40:22)
    at next_ (/Users/darceymckelvey/Documents/auth/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/hooks-fixed/hooks.js:75:26)
    at fnWrapper (/Users/darceymckelvey/Documents/auth/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/hooks-fixed/hooks.js:186:18)
    at /Users/darceymckelvey/Documents/auth/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:290:15
    at /Users/darceymckelvey/Documents/auth/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:191:14
    at /Users/darceymckelvey/Documents/auth/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:135:9
    at /Users/darceymckelvey/Documents/auth/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/collection.js:484:20
    at /Users/darceymckelvey/Documents/auth/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/collection.js:597:14
    at /Users/darceymckelvey/Documents/auth/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/bulk/unordered.js:469:9
    at resultHandler (/Users/darceymckelvey/Documents/auth/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/bulk/unordered.js:416:5)
    at /Users/darceymckelvey/Documents/auth/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:778:13
    at Callbacks.emit (/Users/darceymckelvey/Documents/auth/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:95:3)
    at null.messageHandler (/Users/darceymckelvey/Documents/auth/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:249:23)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/darceymckelvey/Documents/auth/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:262:22)
```

Comment: The condition is probably false, as `error` will only be defined if `err.code === 11000`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry - just reread your question/code - this is a scoping issue:

```
user.save(function(err) {
    if (err) {
      var error = 'Something bad happened, try again!';
      if(err.code === 11000) {
        error = 'That email is already taken, try another.';
      }
      res.render('register.jade', { error: error });
```

Comment: Changed it to that and fixed it but it no longer goes to /dashboard. It doesn't register the account just submits and clears the form.

Comment: I tried putting the res.render line within the second if statement but it didn't fix it. I'm new to programming so I am assuming I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: You don't want to put the res.render line within the second if statement.

you want it to default to this error message:
'Something bad happened, try again!'

Since you're new to this - try using more primitive logging methods:
console.log('error: ' + error);

or

alert('error: ' + error);

then when you can see the code-flow - then try switching to res.render(..) or res.redirect(..) function calls.